# Distinct function does not give output

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a query to fetch records from an oracle table. But when I use a distinct function It goes into time out and does not give any results. Is there an alternative to using a distinct and still get results?

Only Test3 works without distinct. In Test2, I tried to use a subquery but doesn't work either.

In the sample of the table, there are more than 100k rows. But I have shown only 1 percent of it.

Table1:

```
id                     country
100003                 Poland
PL10005-100001         England
100007                 Finland 
100005                 Sweden
100004                 Norway
100002                 Chicago
```

Table2:

```
id                     country
100003                Poland
100007                Finland
100006                Austria
100004                Norway
100001                India
```

Test1:

```
SELECT
distinct
t1.id,
t2.country,
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Test2:

```
Select distinct
id, 
country
from 
(
select 
t1.id,
t2.country,
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id)
```

Test3:

```
SELECT
t1.id,
t2.country,
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Do you have the index on the `ID` column on both tables? also, Is there any index on the `country` column?

Comment: beside from syntax error ,`distinct` sometime will greatly drop the performance. because in some circumstances it will cause you to `order` data with some not so efficient way. make sure you have proper index your data or order beforehand.

Comment: No index is set for any of the columns.

Comment: try index first or use a `group by` which contain every column you have. this sometime will help `distinct` work better.

Comment: Let me try, thanks.

Comment: @T.Peter this is not quite working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Cached view, I was able to fix this distinct view issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably not `distinct`.  The issue is probably that you have zillions of duplicate rows.  Without `distinct`, Oracle is probably returning rows as they are generated, so the time to the *first* row is quick.  But getting the whole result set would take a long, long time.

You can see if there are duplicates by using:

```
select id, count(*)
from table1
group by id
having count(*) > 1
```

And:

```
select id, count(*)
from table2
group by id
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can get the size of the result set (without generating it) using:

```
select sum(t1.cnt * t2.cnt)
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from table1
      group by id
      having count(*) > 1 
     ) t1 join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from table2
      group by id
      having count(*) > 1
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

I am guessing this is much larger than you would expect.  You need to figure out what to do about duplicates to fix your performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your join statement has the wrong syntax. Try this:

```
SELECT
distinct
t1.id,
t2.country
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this issue but it was just my mistake to have put where instead of on but this is the query I have and for this, the distinct does not work.